# POST Request to other server

Tags: laravel, cors

I want to send a POST request to an other server with Ajax when a button is pressed.
But I'm getting the error message:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/hello. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://my.site.com' is therefore not allowed access.**

This is my button:

```
<button id="my-button">Click me pls</button>
```

And this is the JS code:

```
document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/hello', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', "<...>");

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    };

    request.send("message=Thisismymessage&" +
                "_token=<...>");

    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

/hello should process and store the message in the database.

On the server side I'm using Laravel 5.4.

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/hello', 'Auth\RegisterController@hello')
    ->middleware('cors');
```

The cors Middleware looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https//my.site.com')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept, authorization');
    }
}
```

The hello method in the RegisterController just takes the data (in this case the message "Thisismymessage") and puts it in the database.

```
protected function hello(Request $request)
{
    // Working with the data...
}
```

Do any of you have an idea how to fix it?

And my additional question ist: is there a way to "generate" the CSRF token from Laravel from an other application which doesn't use Laravel as framework or do I have to copy & paste it manually?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to post to another domain? There are protections in place like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: You can make make an api call to generate the form which you will later submit to the backend again, so while making that form the csrf_token could already be added

Comment: @Jerodev It don't have a choice, I have to do it this way. And I'm aware of the protection, this is the reason I'm asking.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi Thanks. :)

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to make it happen despite the protection?

Comment: @Rabbitrun check the answer I gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could recommend a little hack to solve the second question, i.e:

> is there a way to "generate" the CSRF token from Laravel from an other application which doesn't use Laravel as framework or do I have to copy & paste it manually?

1. Create an end point in the backend of your app to generate a view of the form. You should already include the csrf_token field when making this form, so that at your front end you have a complete form which you will submit again.

> This look like a snake long way.

2. The more recommended way is that: it appears you are building an api, this makes it easy because its stateless. Use an api key example with [JWT-AUTH](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), so that you don't have to deal any thing with csrf token.

**For the first question:**

You should just sort out the cors issue from your backend a good one is [Cors middleware for Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Others: **Not recommended** but for test purpose you can add these in the `constructor` of your controller to see how your app fair:

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
```

> Remember: This is useful only if you are doing a test.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I will try it this way.